# Make mouse-scrolling and -copying work in tmux under urxvt

Tags: tmux, urxvt

If I add `setw -g mode-mouse on` to my `~/.tmux.conf` I can get the following to work in xterm + tmux:

1. Click and hold left mouse button in the terminal
2. Scroll up with mouse wheel
3. Position cursor at some desired letter/column
4. Release left mouse button

However, when I try to do the same with tmux in urxvt, I am unable to position the cursor after scrolling up - every mouse movement simply scrolls further upwards. Does anyone know how to get the two to play nice?